# onLocationChanged not getting called in ics android

Tags: android, gps, maps

I'm working on gps location app, my problem is that on my **Galaxy S2 ICS 4.0.3**, gps takes too long to call onLocationChanged, it takes very long to lock, sometimes doesn't lock at all, code below.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();

if (lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, listener);
else
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 0, listener);


// Location Listener class
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
     if(loc != null)
    txtLocation.setText("Lat: "+loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "+loc.getLongitude());
     else
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loc == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) { }

}
```

I've tested this code on **Galaxy y (2.3.6)** and **HTC Explorer (2.3.6)** and it works really fast and location is obtained like in 4-5 seconds!!

Now is it my galaxy s2 or ics problem because I've rooted my **S2 with XXLPJ firmware**

what am I supposed to do to get rid of this issue??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this rom ? unofficial roms can do that to your phone

Comment: I follow [this](http://techdraginfo.blogspot.com/2012/06/install-android-ics-403-xxlpj-firmware.html) to upgrade my s2 to ics 4.0.3, sorry for that **customer rom**

Comment: well, we can't do anything about that, when I restarted my s2 then location was locked immediately, I've heard about that issue with other people too.. try to place device where no obstacles

Answer (score 0):

Many GPS devices use the Extra XTRA data to make quick sattelite lock, but this data needs to be updated maximum every 7 days.

You have some program in the Google Play that have an option to force this update (as for example [GPS Status](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lY2xpcHNpbS5ncHNzdGF0dXMyIl0.)). You need to be connected to Internet for the data to be downloaded.

If that doesn't solve, than you may be facing a ROM issue or a GPS failure.

Regards.

Comment: I don't know whats the problem, in morning time gps was working and now again its taking too long :(

Comment: It looks like an outdated xtra file. Install Gps Status , select Tools and then A-GPS. There you can update file with sattelites location information.